# Django - Reverse for 'list1' not found. 'list1' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-2.1

I'm trying to upload a file, I got the code from some website. Which was written in older Django version and i'm using a latest version. Got some errors while running, fixed them by going through stackoverflow. But now i'm stuck with no clue with the error mentioned, this is my first Django project. Thanks in advance.
Below are my files

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Document
from .forms import DocumentForm
from django.urls import reverse
#

def list1(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myproject.myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render(request,
        'csv_manipulation/list.html',
    )

def index(request):
    return render('myapp/index.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import list1

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', list1),
    path(r'list/', list1),
]
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file',
    )
```

**list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Minimal Django File Upload Example</title>
        </head>

        <body>
                <!-- List of uploaded documents -->
                {% if documents %}
                        <ul>
                        {% for document in documents %}
                                <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}
                                <img src="{{ document.docfile.url }}" alt="{{ document.docfile.name }}">
                                </a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                {% else %}
                        <p>No documents.</p>
                {% endif %}

                <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
                <form action="{% url 'list1' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
                        <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} </p>
                        <p>
                                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                                {{ form.docfile }}
                        </p>
                        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
                </form>

        </body>

</html>
```

**Error**

```
Template error:
In template C:\Users\nmasthex\projects\adept_proj\adept_stage1\csv_manipulation\templates\csv_manipulation\list.html, error at line 23
       Reverse for 'list1' not found. 'list1' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
       13 :                                 <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}
       14 :                                 <img src="{{ document.docfile.url }}" alt="{{ document.docfile.name }}">
       15 :                                 </a></li>
       16 :                         {% endfor %}
       17 :                         </ul>
       18 :                 {% else %}
       19 :                         <p>No documents.</p>
       20 :                 {% endif %}
       21 : 
       22 :                 <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
       23 :                 <form action=" {% url 'list1' %} " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       24 :                         {% csrf_token %}
       25 :                         <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
       26 :                         <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} </p>
       27 :                         <p>
       28 :                                 {{ form.docfile.errors }}
       29 :                                 {{ form.docfile }}
       30 :                         </p>
       31 :                         <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
       32 :                 </form>
       33 : 


    Traceback:

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
      34.             response = get_response(request)

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\projects\adept_proj\adept_stage1\csv_manipulation\views.py" in list1
      29.         'csv_manipulation/list.html',

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
      36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
      62.     return template.render(context, request)

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
      61.             return self.template.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
      171.                     return self._render(context)

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
      163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
      937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
      904.             return self.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
      442.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
      90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

    File "C:\Users\nmasthex\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
      622.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /csv_manipulation/
    Exception Value: Reverse for 'list1' not found. 'list1' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a namespace to your url for this particular view.

```
path(r'list/', list1, name=‘namespace’)
```

Then in your template, use:

```
{% url ‘app_name:namespace’ %}
```

N.B. The namespace variable in your `path()` can be anything you want:

```
path(r'list/', list1, name=‘foo’)
```

Then:

```
{% url ‘app_name:foo’ %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to add third parameter to url path. If you want to use 
`{% url 'list1' %}` you'll need add name
`path(r'list/', list1, name='list1'),`